# Force CSV delimiter

Tags: php, csv

(with PHP)

I need to check a CSV file uploaded by a customer. Specifically I need to verify that this CSV has as delimiter just the ';' not other delimiter are allowed.

What the best way to handle this for you?

Thank you.

Comment: actually i'm trying to get the number of the column of the file. If it's just one i suppose that the delimiter is wrong...but i know that this is not the best way.. Have you better idea?

Comment: if you hone csv parsing code, and it fails, then the file is probably not the format you wanted.

Comment: i have started from this library: http://code.google.com/p/parsecsv-for-php/

this always parse the file...so if the csv have a wrong delimiter return just 1 column... while i would like return an error....

Answer (score 0):

If you know the values of the first line, you could try to identify the delimiter by reading the Nth character of the first line, for example:

```
$csvdata = "delimiter;test\r\netc;herp"; // Contents of the uploaded file

$delimiter = substr($csvdata, strlen("delimiter "), 1);
echo $delimiter;
```

I suggest you use xlsx filetype. It's a lot easier to handle than CSV and does not have issues with Mac and DOS line endings and encoding.

Comment: ok Diamondo25, i will try something like that...! thank you :-)